# SaaS billing for Rails app: Chargify, PayPal or...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, billing, paypal-subscriptions

I am in my sophomore year of programming in general and Ruby on Rails more specifically. I have created several apps and finally have one that I would like to start charging for. I have never implemented something like this before and I feel like (from what I have read) most of the docs provided are a bit over my head. I don't mind diving in but before I did I wanted to get some opinion from those more experienced about what is the simplest way to implement a model for charging my User a month fee for use. Two notes:

1. My App contains Users already and I will be introducing a new section of the app which I only want to give access to those who pay.
2. I don't mind sending them to a third party page for payment.

From what I can find, it seems like both PayPal and Chargify do a decent job of providing help for this type of integration. What are your thoughts about which type of solution is best for a newbie to this space.

Comment: Not really an answer, but my personal experience with PayPal was pretty good. I implemented it about a year ago, and at the time, I had about a year of part time PHP development experience. If you haven't worked with APIs before, the idea of web services will take a bit of getting used to, but it's definitely doable; it was for me. PayPal, at least when I used it, didn't require any libraries; just a HTTP request and response. If you're working with subscriptions, you're going to be using the IPN a lot. It probably took me 8-10 hours to get the whole API integrated into my system.

Comment: Can it be used such that it sends notice back to your app that your particular user has paid? And then can it notify your app such that if the user has canceled you can change the state of that user record. Not even sure if I am saying this all correctly. Make sense?

Comment: It notifies your server whenever anything happens: recurring payment success/failure, subscription, cancellation. There are a few steps they encourage you to follow like pinging them back to make sure the information isn't spoofed, but it's pretty simple and pretty comprehensive. When I used it (I, too, was preparing a subscription service that's still active now), I didn't come across anything I identified as a missing feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll admit I'm biased since I'm one of the founders of Chargify :-).

But before that I helped build 7-8 companies, most recently Engine Yard, and I really, really wish we'd had something like Chargify back then. I remember thinking, "Man, we need something like 'Basecamp for Billing'... it should be simple, sign up with a credit card, define products & pricing, and get going". So I found the Chargify/GrasshopperGroup folks and joined the team.

Chargify takes it up a level from what we found with payment gateway offerings and things like PayPal... with Chargify, you define products, prices, coupon codes, metered-usage units, etc., and let Chargify do as much as you want. The system emails your customers when their cards get declined or expire, and directs them to a URL to fix the problem, etc.

Billing gets complex as a business grows. I tell callers that if their needs are really simple, then they may indeed be okay with Auth.Net's ARB service or another like it, but as soon as your needs even begin to get less simple (ie, customers change plans mid-cycle and want proration), then Chargify really makes your life easier.

And as Rails folks ourselves, we're always working to make the service better, so you'll get more and more services as time progresses. And you can actually call us 24/7 and get someone on the phone! Our Level 1 phone team knows the product better and better each week and can send the call to Level 2 if they don't know the answer.

So, you're getting a good piece of software, plus a good team who's here for you to develop new features and provide support if you need it.

Sorry this sounds like an ad; it is, partly, of course. But it's also just a reflection of my frustration trying to build this at earlier companies, and my enthusiasm for being part of Chargify now and helping merchants not focus on recurring billing :-).

Comment: chargify has been consistently one of the worst dev experiences i continue to have. i am encountering yet another huge pain point of which there have been 10 in the last year. 

all we wanted was a way to direct the user to an external place to handle all their payment and product changes. chargify does NOT offer this and we have had to handle lots of complex logic to handle all the different migration and scenarios between simple trialing, credit card and invoice subscriptions.

i will never recommend chargify and urge anyone to reconsider if you think it looks simple.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/

At a previous place of employment, we used Brain Tree, and I only heard good things about it though I wasn't (and still aren't, but trying) a programmer at the time. It seems to be a little bit more expensive than the big guys - but has more freedom as well.

It might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

**Charging System or Billing System?**

Talking with a number of folks building businesses in the Ruby community, I thinks it's important to note that simply collecting customer payments and scalable billing are two rather unique animals. Today's SaaS companies are not always aware of the difference.

Hitting credit cards for $39.95 on a monthly basis is something most of the "payment tools" mentioned here do well. Yet, when one needs to incorporate a complex billing algorithm (charge model), client contracts, promotional codes, freemium, tiered, rollover or metered usage, or integration with other internal systems, They need more than a payment machine. They really need a "smarter" billing system that leverages a payment gateway, but does far more than simply hitting cards on a monthly basis.

Also, if one has a significant number of clients or volume a system that scales is key. For research check out more mid-tier *billing systems* like http://www.metanga.com or http://www.zuora.com.

Answer (score 0):

To take payment you're going to need a few things:

1. A bank account to put the money in
2. A payment gateway
3. An SSL certificate (this can be tricky if you're in the cloud)

The beauty of products like chargify or braintree is that they give you a nice API for dealing with card events like expiry or failed payments and can sometimes also act as a payment gateway.

I integrated with cheddar getter (https://cheddargetter.com/) in an afternoon.  There's a ruby gem (https://github.com/ads/cheddargetter) and they have a payment gateway service, but I haven't used that so don't want to comment on its value.

Payment is an annoyingly complicated process and you have to pay everyone down the chain, the hardest part is making sure your service is competitively priced but not priced in such a way where you're not making any profit.

Here's some more links you might be interested in reading:

http://www.activemerchant.org/
http://recurly.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've used PayPal's Express Payments with ActiveMerchant before, because there's no buy-in cost; PayPal just takes their slice of each transaction, so I don't have to worry about paying fees to a ton of different providers. The downsides are well-documented, though, as well - specifically, if PayPal decides that you're doing something shady and decides to freeze your money, you're up the creek without a paddle. That's a calculated risk you have to evaluate, though.

You might look at [Saasy](https://github.com/maccman/saasy) if you don't want to roll your own full solution, though. It seems to integrate well with existing apps.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMerchant is definitely the way to go to get integration with PayPal or any of the creditcard gateways like Braintree (highly recommended) or Authorize.net (good and cheap).  The [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas/), which I authored, uses it as the basis for a full recurring billing solution that you can integrate with your app.

Regarding your follow-on question about PayPal, ActiveMerchant makes it easy to use their API or IPN to get information back about the transaction status.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a ton of experience with this and the first question that you need to ask yourself is "how important is recurring billing?"  If recurring billing is a requirement then by all means use Chargify, Recurly or the like.  They are all pretty good.

If, however, you are simply looking to outsource your payment process (as I typically am) so you don't have to deal with PCI compliance (which is a nightmare) then you have a lot LESS viable options IMO.  You can use PayPal, Amazon or Google Checkout, but they all have downsides.  PayPals user experience is terrible and many people get confused by it believing they need a PayPal account to complete the purchase.  Google Checkout REQUIRES the user to either have or create a Google Account, which is ridiculous and Amazon is ok but like Google Checkout requires an Amazon account.

WePay is my personal favorite right now for outsourced billing but is very lean and you have to use their checkout process.  Their staff and API is awesome though.

What I would LOVE to see if a Chargify-like solution that is focused on ONE OFF sales.  Something that let's me host the entire checkout process on THEIR PCI Compliant server but allows me to customize not just the look and feel but form.  If I wanted to ask for extra info, like a username and password, I can.  If I don't need shipping address, I can remove it.  If I only want the CC number, CVV and exp date without billing address I can do that, etc.

But to the best of my knowledge that does not currently exist.  Don't use Chargify for one-off transactions.  While they support it the checkout process is VERY clunky for one offs (displays things like $0 setup fee, which means nothing when someone is buying a shirt or one time downloadable material and is merely confusing).

Good luck!

Comment: btw - I should add that I've used Recurly, Chargify, PP, WePay AND currently have my own in-house solution using ActiveMerchant and Auth.net in terms of experience.